UISlider triggers reorder on Silicon Mac's UITableView
When I run my iOS app on Apple Silicon Mac (ARM) in "Designed for iPad" mode, I'm not able to use a UISlider contained in a reorderable tableview cell. Dragging the slider triggers a reorder of the cell rather than sliding the slider.

This behaves correctly on iOS devices: when I drag the slider, no reorder is triggered.
I tried a Swift version which yields the same result.
Here's how the UITableView is setup:
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
[self.tableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];

Here's the cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell*cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddRow"];
    
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"AddRow"] autorelease];
    
        UISlider *slider = [[UISlider new] autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
    
        return cell;
    }



[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];


Well, there's your problem. Being able to edit, meaning that the user can rearrange or delete cells, is incompatible with the notion of being able to do things in the cell. Just the opposite: the slider should be disabled when the cell/table is in edit mode.

Yes, possibly. But on iOS, one can only reorder the cells by dragging the burger icon, and thus the slider is usable even when the table is editing. In my view, that is the correct behavior. Whichever way is correct, it doesn't behave the same between iOS and Mac, which is a shame.
